# How to disable CTRL ALT key on windows 7?

Tags: delphi

I know the only way to do that is to remap keys with regedit.
Have someone has done that with delphi ? (disable it and enable it again)

http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/25/Securing-Windows-For-Use-As-A-Kiosk

Comment: Well, Delphi lets you modify registry keys. Just do the same thing using Delphi code.

Comment: What is your question and how does it relate to delphi?

Comment: yes: but how: this is my question

Comment: Follow the steps in the manual registry changes and do the same thing in code. Do you want us to teach you how to use the `TRegistry`? Or were you expecting someone to do the research and write the code for you? You need to learn how to use the `TRegistry` and tackle this one yourself. I could write this for you, but would you learn anything?

Comment: You modify the same keys that article tells you to, using `TRegistry` or the Windows API. A search for `[delphi] registry` or `[delphi] TRegistry` can turn up some useful information to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information in the article would translate to Delphi as follows:

```
uses
  Registry;

const
  DisableScancodes: packed array[0..11] of DWORD = (
    $00000000, // version = 0
    $00000000, // flags = 0
    $00000009, // # of mappings = 9
    $E05B0000, // disable Windows key
    $E05C0000, // disable Windows key
    $E05D0000, // disable Windows menu key
    $00440000, // disable F10 key
    $001D0000, // disable Left Ctrl key
    $00380000, // disable Left Alt key
    $E01D0000, // disable Right Ctrl key
    $E0380000, // disable Right Alt key
    $00000000  // end of list
  );

var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout', True) then
    begin
      try
        // to enable the mapping
        Reg.WriteBinaryData('Scancode Map', DisableScancodes, SizeOf(DisableScancodes));

        // to disable the mapping
        Reg.DeleteValue('Scancode Map');
      finally
        Reg.CloseKey;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you need to be more dynamic about which scancodes you enable/disable, you will have to use `TRegistry.ReadBinaryData()` to read the current `Scancode Map` value (if it exists), modify it as needed, and then save the changes using `TRegistry.WriteBinaryData()`.  Try something like this:

```
unit ScanCodeMap;

interface

type
  TMappedScancode = record
    Scancode: WORD;
    MappedTo: WORD;
  end;

procedure AddScancodeMappings(const Values: array of TMappedScancode);
procedure AddScancodeMapping(const Value: TMappedScancode);
procedure AddScancodeMapping(Scancode, MappedTo: WORD);

procedure RemoveScancodeMappings(const Scancodes: array of WORD);
procedure RemoveScancodeMapping(Scancode: WORD);

procedure DisableScancodes(Scancodes: array of WORD);
procedure DisableScancode(Scancode: WORD);

implementation

uses
  Windows, Registry;

type
  PScancodeMapHdr = ^TScancodeMapHdr;
  TScancodeMapHdr = packed record
    Version: DWORD;
    Flags: DWORD;
    NumMappings: DWORD;
  end;

  TScancodeMap = record
    Version: DWORD;
    Flags: DWORD;
    Mappings: array of TMappedScancode;
  end;

procedure AddScancodesToMap(var Map: TScancodeMap; const Values: array of TMappedScancode);
var
  I, J, Idx: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(Values) do
  begin
    Idx := -1;
    for J := 0 to High(Map.Mappings) do
    begin
      if Map.Mappings[J].Scancode = Values[I].Scancode then
      begin
        Idx := J;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    if Idx = -1 then
    begin
      SetLength(Map.Mappings, Length(Map.Mappings)+1);
      Idx := High(Map.Mappings);
    end;
    Map.Mappings[Idx].MappedTo := Values[I].MappedTo;
  end;
end;

procedure RemoveScancodesFromMap(var Map: TScancodeMap; const Scancodes: array of WORD);
var
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(Scancodes) do
  begin
    for J := 0 to High(Map.Mappings) do
    begin
      if Map.Mappings[J].Scancode = Scancodes[I] then
      begin
        if J < High(Map.Mappings) then
          Move(Map.Mappings[J+1], Map.Mappings[J], (High(Mappings)-J) * SizeOf(TMappedScancode));
        SetLength(Map.Mappings, Length(Map.Mappings)-1);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure WriteScanCodeMap(const Map: TScancodeMap);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  Data: array of Byte;
  Tmp: PByte;
  Hdr: PScancodeMapHdr;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Length(Map.Mappings) > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Data, sizeof(TScancodeMapHdr) + (Length(Map.Mappings) + 1) * SizeOf(DWORD));
    Tmp := PByte(Data);

    Hdr := PScancodeMapHdr(Tmp);
    Hdr.Version := Map.Version;
    Hdr.Flags := Map.Flags;
    Hdr.NumMappings := Length(Map.Mappings) + 1;
    Inc(Tmp, SizeOf(TScancodeMapHdr));

    for I := 0 to High(Map.Mappings) do
    begin
      PDWORD(Tmp)^ := (DWORD(Map.Mappings[0].Scancode) shr 16) or DWORD(Map.Mappings[0].MappedTo);
      Inc(Tmp, SizeOf(DWORD));
    end;

    PDWORD(Tmp)^ := 0;
  end;

  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout', True) then
    begin
      try
        if Length(Data) > 0 then
          Reg.WriteBinaryData('Scancode Map', Data[0], Length(Data))
        else
          Reg.DeleteValue('Scancode Map');
      finally
        Reg.CloseKey;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure ReadScanCodeMap(var Map: TScancodeMap);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  Size: Integer;
  Data: array of Byte;
  Tmp: PByte;
  Hdr: PScancodeMapHdr;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Map.Version := 0;
  Map.Flags := 0;
  SetLength(Map.Mappings, 0);

  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout') then
    begin
      try
        Size := Reg.GetDataSize('Scancode Map');
        if Size > SizeOf(TScancodeMapHdr) then
        begin
          SetLength(Data, Size);
          Reg.ReadBinaryData('Scancode Map', Data[0], Size);
          Tmp := PByte(Data);

          Hdr := PScancodeMapHdr(Tmp);
          Map.Version := Hdr.Version;
          Map.Flags := Hdr.Flags;
          Inc(Tmp, SizeOf(TScancodeMapHdr));

          if Hdr.NumMappings > 1 then
          begin
            SetLength(Map.Mappings, Hdr.NumMappings-1);
            for I := 0 to High(Map.Mappings) do
            begin
              Map.Mappings[I].Scancode := HIWORD(PDWORD(Tmp)^);
              Map.Mappings[I].MappedTo := LOWORD(PDWORD(Tmp)^);
            end;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Reg.CloseKey;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure AddScancodeMappings(const Values: array of TMappedScancode);
var
  Map: TScancodeMap;
begin
  ReadScanCodeMap(Map); 
  AddScancodesToMap(Map, Values);
  WriteScanCodeMap(Map);
end;

procedure AddScancodeMapping(const Value: TMappedScancode);
begin
  AddScancodeMappings([Value]);
end;

procedure AddScancodeMapping(Scancode, MappedTo: WORD);
var
  Value: array[0..0] of TMappedScancode;
begin
  Value[0].Scancode := Scancode;
  Value[0].MappedTo := MappedTo;
  AddScancodeMappings([Value]);
end;

procedure RemoveScancodeMappings(const Scancodes: array of WORD);
var
  Map: TScancodeMap;
begin
  ReadScanCodeMap(Map); 
  RemoveScancodesFromMap(Map, Scancodes);
  WriteScanCodeMap(Map);
end;

procedure RemoveScancodeMapping(Scancode: WORD);
begin
  RemoveScancodeMappings([Scancode]);
end;

procedure DisableScancodes(Scancodes: array of WORD);
var
  Values: array of TMappedScancode;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Values, Length(Scancodes));
  for I := 0 to High(Mappings) do
  begin
    Values[I].Scancode := Scancodes[I];
    Values[I].MappedTo := $0000;
  end;
  AddScancodeMappings(Values);
end;

procedure DisableScancode(Scancode: WORD);
begin
  AddScancodeMapping(Scancode, $0000);
end;

end.
```

Then you can do this:

```
uses
  ScanCodeMap;

const
  Scancodes: packed array[0..7] of WORD = (
    $E05B, // Windows key
    $E05C, // Windows key
    $E05D, // Windows menu key
    $0044, // F10 key
    $001D, // Left Ctrl key
    $0038, // Left Alt key
    $E01D, // Right Ctrl key
    $E038  // Right Alt key
  );

procedure DisableCtrlAltDel;
begin
  DisableScancodes(Scancodes);
end;

procedure EnableCtrlAltDel;
begin
  RemoveScancodeMappings(Scancodes);
end;
```

Comment: Two notes: First since you are trying to modiffy registry in Local machine branch you will need to run your application with elevated privilegies to do so. Second changing registry for this may be quite dangerous especially if your application crashes before you manage to revert the registry changes back to default. CTRL and ALT keys my become disabled pemamenty. If my memory serves me correctly something like this can also be done by using a systemwide keyboard hook but I'm not sure.

Comment: @SilverWarior, I wouldn't call it dangerous. I can think of this as, either is your app malware, or a *service* that is turning the machine into the kiosk mode. If it's a malware, who cares if something bad happens. If it's a kiosk switching service, you need to be more careful, keeping some backdoor for the service tasks. But it's trivial to write a service application that won't crash (system can even auto-restart it for you).

Comment: If you are preparing computer to work in kiosk mode then I would suggest making a shell replacement instead as this way you get much more control of what can be or can't be done on that computer. Granted it does take much more work but final results could be much better. You can even use SharpEviro (open sourced shell replacement for windows made with Delphi) for quicker start. You can find SharpEviro on sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpe/

Comment: @SilverWarior, another note is that this code not works to disable **ALT** keys. Tested on Windows 7 x64